# Error while Login with Facebook in Flutter SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query. [extra]:

Tags: flutter, facebook-authentication

After initialising flutter login like this:
final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(permissions: const ['email', 'public_profile'],loginBehavior: LoginBehavior.dialogOnly);

it is getting loginResult message like:

> SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query.
> [extra]:

Comment: Hey Basically Facebook Developers has sent email regarding our auth flow is not correct so we have sent proper documentation with logs and screen recordings and app is live again, the error is there because app was disabled from Developers console

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you could check

1. Check if you are a tester in fb apps dashboard. If not add a tester account
2. Add one more scope user_friends along with email and public profile
3. Check the key hash value in fb dashboard which you obtained from the jks you are trying to build.
4. Check if your fb app id is correct

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Here

5. You can also add android value here

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```